# Cent OS 7 - remove sudoer user without deleting that user

Tags: centos7, sudo

I want to remove sudo permission from sudoer user without deleting it. I got this answer in debian as:

```
sudo deluser USERNAME sudo
```

But it doesn't work in centos. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest and fastest solution is to remove from `/etc/sudoers` file or if your configuration based on files in `/etc/sudoers.d`, just remove all occurrences for this user in files mentioned before.

**NOTE:** To edit `/etc/sudoers`, please use `visudo` command.

Comment: I imagine the user could also be part of a group which can sudo in which case /etc/groups may need to be edited.